# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'message_handler'

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

exactly **'str'** object.

```
import telebot  
bot = telebot.TeleBot = ('api') 
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text_messages(message):     
if message.text == "hello":   
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "hello")
bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

what`s wrong?

I'm trying to create a telegram bot for the first time

Answer (score 1):

```
bot = telebot.TeleBot = ('api')
```

should be

```
bot = telebot.TeleBot('api')
```

The current version just makes telebot.Telebot to be equal to 'api', then bot to be equal to telebot.Telebot

As a result, bot equals 'api' which is a str, hence the error.